# Pausing and resuming playback where left off

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have a 10 frames on main timeline with a movieclip on each frame. Every movieclip contains some animation and sound (placed on separate layer).

I need to create 2 buttons to control the animation: a Pause and Resume.

Here is what i have tried:

```
on(release) {
    _root.mc.play();    
}

on(release) {
    _root.mc.stop();    
}
```

This seems to work on animations, but it does not pause the voiceover(the sound).
What is the best way to go about it. I need this for ActionScript 2.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the sounds type as `Stream`.

[image]